# Blocking gzip HTTP content with Iptables or Snort?

Tags: iptables, gzip, snort

I'm looking to drop a connection if a website contains a certain word or phrase. The issue is, the site is typically compressed with gzip. Any ideas?

Comment: transparent http proxy like squid?

Answer (score 1):

`snort` knows how to handle compressed HTTP requests and responses. So configuring snort in inline mode and writing rules with `file_data` before the `content` keyword would do it.

Comment: Do you have a link to a guide or similar? Sounds perfect